# Gmail SendEmail Quota - Decrementing Bug/issue

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, sendmail, gmail-api

To reproduce the bug, make an onEdit trigger for send_email().

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var cell = ss.getActiveCell();
var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
var row = range.getRow();
var emailQuotaRemaining = MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota();
function send_email(){
GmailApp.sendEmail('my_address@yahoo.com','Subject','Body');
ss.getRange(row,2).setValue("You have " +emailQuotaRemaining+' emails left');
}
```

You will not receive duplicated emails, but the quota is decrementing by 2 sometimes, and even by 3 or 4 in rare cases.

After typing 1,2,3 consecutively several times, it is obvious that the decrementing is chaotic and that once the sendemail function was not even triggered. Even more, I received only 14 emails instead of 19.

For the code above, the sheet looks like this:

```
1   You have 95 emails left
2   You have 92 emails left
3   You have 94 emails left

1   You have 91 emails left
2   You have 90 emails left
3   You have 89 emails left

1   You have 89 emails left
2   You have 88 emails left
3   

1   You have 86 emails left
2   You have 85 emails left
3   You have 85 emails left

1   You have 85 emails left
2   You have 85 emails left
3   You have 84 emails left

1   You have 83 emails left
2   You have 82 emails left
3   You have 80 emails left
```

Any workaround for this?

Comment: You should add this to the Apps Script Issue Tracker.  [Link to Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list)

Comment: I have already added it. It is Issue #5674.

Answer (score 0):

It's not just the `MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota()` that's causing a problem; or it may be an issue with the installable trigger.  I've reproduced the problem with the following code.  The following code works, UNLESS, you edit the sheet very fast.  So, I'm guessing that there is a lag in Google's server.

```
function sendEmail(e) {
  var lockt = LockService.getScriptLock();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  ss.getRange(row,2).setValue("You have " +'99'+' emails left');
  LockService.getScriptLock().releaseLock();
};
```